# How do I distribute a stand-alone made with BGE (Blender Game Engine)?

Tags: game-engine

I have created a simple stand-alone using the BGE that I would like to distribute to various people in a manner that involves as little effort on their part as possible.

I can easily create my stand-alone and run it on the machine that I have created it on.  I'm using a PC.

However, when I move the files to another location within my computer, the runtime does not work.  I'm assuming that the BGE needs to know the exact path of the various .dll files to work properly.   I would like to be able send the entire package to a friend and have them unzip (or "install") the package and have it work.

Any ideas?  Am I doing anything wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't it work if you export your game to a folder and then just copy the whole folder?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you export you should do `File/External Data/Make All Files Relative` and save.

This ensures the paths are relative to the current blend file.

Be aware: This influences the current blend only. When you link to blend files that refer to other files, this file needs to be changed too.

When you export from WinOS you need to deliver all files from your export directory to ensure all the libraries (.dll) are available.

Comment: Thanks!

I assume you mean "make all PATHS relative" as, in Blender 2.79, that is the option that is closest.